# Browserify require file with dynamic path fails, but works when using hard-coded path

Tags: reactjs, browserify

I'm getting started with Browserify and I'm trying to require an array of files, based on a config file named `components.coffee`. I use React with CoffeeScript, but I doubt it's related to the issue itself.

*index.cjsx*

```
path = require 'path'

componentList = require '../commons/components'

components = componentList.map (component) ->
    console.log path.relative(__dirname, component)
    console.log '../commons/button/button.doc.js'
    console.log '../commons/button/button.doc.js' is path.relative(__dirname, component)
    console.log require(path.relative(__dirname, component))
    console.log require '../commons/button/button.doc.js'
    require(path.relative(__dirname, component))
```

*commons/components.coffee*

```
module.exports = [
    "../commons/button/button.doc.js"
]
```

*Output:*
[image]

*Output when removing the line `console.log require '../commons/button/button.doc.js'`*:
[image]

If I don't require the file using an hard-coded path, it fails. I don't explain why since the hardcoded path and the dynamic path are equals.

I guess it's something related to Browserify, probably a caching issue that is resolved when the module is required through a hard-coded string. But I don't really have a clue.

I the meantime I'm gonna use a workaround, but I'd like to understand what's happening here! :)

---

My solution was to change my design. Instead of having a `components.coffee` which returned an array of strings, it now returns an array of loaded files.

*commons/components.coffee*

```
module.exports = [
    require "../commons/button/button.doc.js"
]
```

And then, in my *index.cjsx* I just load it:

```
components = require '../commons/components'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is by design. You can find more info about it [here](https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/issues/341) and [here](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/664).

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand how I'm supposed to do it then.

Comment: According to the creators there are no workarounds; "browserify doesn't work with conditional requires and can't be made to work with arbitrary dynamic requires without solving the halting problem first. Do something different instead. This is a dead end."

Comment: Well, there is not much to say, I read this and was still trying to find a solution, I just did. Thanks you :)